# Please help me identify this plant, so i may plant a transplant of this species

Tags: identification

[image]

I have recently found the same type of unknown plant in the edge of my yard. I have dug them up and intend to transplant the huge bulbous rooted plants but I don't know what they actually are.

Comment: Could you tell us more about it, where are you geographically, what season it is, how large are the leaves and the plant ?

Comment: Also closeups of leaves,root, does the leaves smell when crushed by hand etc.

Comment: Is there one or two plants? One may seems a Solomon's seal (but there are also many other slightly related and cultivated species)